# How will updating kernel affect everything else?

Tags: kernel, debian-wheezy

I'm new to Linux and I'd like to try to upgrade kernel on my little NAS, but I don't really know how it will affect installed packages and user files, and do I really need to upgrade it? Plus the system has `armhf` architecture, will there be any problems?

Now my system has `3.2.26` version of kernel and on `apt-cache search linux-image` I get something with `3.2.0-4` in title. So I'm a bit confused here, is it really newer than my current kernel. And how old my current kernel really is?

Here is `apt-cache search linux-image` output, which one I need to use in my situation:

```
(chroot-debian)~# apt-cache search linux-image
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-mx5 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-mx5
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-omap - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-omap
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-vexpress - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-vexpress
linux-image-3.2.0-4-mx5 - Linux 3.2 for Freescale i.MX51/53
linux-image-3.2.0-4-omap - Linux 3.2 for TI OMAP3+
linux-image-3.2.0-4-vexpress - Linux 3.2 for ARM Ltd. Versatile Express
linux-image-2.6-mx5 - Linux for Freescale MXC/iMX-based (dummy package)
linux-image-2.6-omap - Linux for TI OMAP3+ (dummy package)
linux-image-mx5 - Linux for Freescale i.MX51 (meta-package)
linux-image-omap - Linux for TI OMAP3+ (meta-package)
linux-image-vexpress - Linux for ARM Ltd. Versatile Express (meta-package)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a backup and try it. It'll like work just fine.  If not, you'll learn a lot in your recovery process. (You are already doing backups, right?)

Comment: Well I can backup system, but not 1 Tb of user files. At least user files are safe, I presume?

Comment: No backup? Well, that ought to be your #1 priority before anything else. Seriously. Forget the kernel upgrade until you have backup sorted out.